# KMeans Clustering on Movielens Dataset

Tags: python, k-means, data-science, scikit-image

I am working on the Movielens dataset and I wanted to apply K-Means algorithm on it. I would like to know what columns to choose for this purpose and How can I proceed further Or Should I directly use the KNN algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, K-Means is a clustering Algorithm so you can use it to cluster the movies based on the genres.
Columns: movieId, genres

There's a new dataset which includes relevant tags for each movie, so you can also cluster them based on those tags.

However, you can also make use of K-Nearest Neighbors to find out how users are similar to each other.

In the reviews dataset, you would use the following columns:
Columns: userId, rating

While in the movies dataset you would use the movieId.
The idea is to figure out which movies every user has viewed, then use those movies to compute the similarity index of users (eg; user1, user2)